# swift for iterations not working

Tags: xcode, swift, iteration

Pals,

I am trying to implement "for" iterations in Swift like this:

```
for var i:Int = 0; i < dataCount; i++ {
        println("test")
}
```

But Xcode doesn't understand this syntax, where am I wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me with Xcode 6. I did have to add a `let dataCount = 4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare a value for dataCount:

```
let dataCount = 5
for var i:Int = 0; i < dataCount; i++ {
    println("test")
}
```

Inside a swift file - your first ViewController try:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let dataCount = 5
        for var i:Int = 0; i < dataCount; i++ {
            println("test")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work :( "Expected declaration" and "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'"

Comment: I pasted it to my swift file. I am not using playground.

Comment: Try it in a playground, that is where I tested it.  Inside a swift file I need to see more of your code to find the error.  Can you paste the entire class?

Comment: Playground works fine. I created a new swift file with only one iteration. like your example.

Comment: Yes now it's working for me well. Thanks. stuck with trivial issue :)

Comment: LOL - we all do every day.

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete :Int.

Just use i.  So your code should look like this:

```
for var i = 0; i < dataCount; i++ {
    println("test")
}
```

And like the others said, make sure dataCount has a value.  For example

```
var dataCount = 5
```

That should work.